# C segmentation fault xor char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, segmentation-fault, xor

I want to xor a certain value on all of my chars in a char array. I have some code that works all fine except for the xor line:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void obfuscate(FILE *file, char *input, char *variableName)
{
    int i;
    int size = (int)strlen(input);
    char a = 65;
    fprintf(file, "%s: %s -> ", variableName, input);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        input[i] = (char)(input[i] ^ a);//I am causing a segmentation fault
        fprintf(file, "0x%x, ", input[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char *a = "MyString";
    FILE *file = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    obfuscate(file, a, "a");
    fclose(file);
}
```

I use the normal gcc compiler with `gcc in.c -o out.o` on a linux machine.

If I comment the line with the xor operation it works just fine. Any help is highly appreciated, my own research did not result in a solution.

Comment: you can't override the code section. use dynamic memory for input `char *a`

Comment: ok, can you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: ok, I have already solved it. thank you

Comment: I posted the change as answer

Comment: Ajay correct your code with using a trick. you cant change the contents of an string that defined with char *a = "MyString"; by trying a[0] = 'b'. I guess this is a constant string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below solution with dynamic memory.
In `char *a = "MyString";  char *in = malloc(sizeof(a));`
`a` is pointing to code section we can't alter it. &
`in` is pointing to heap section, so we can modify it any no.of times.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void obfuscate(FILE *file, char *input, char *variableName)
{
    int i;
    int size = (int)strlen(input);
    char a = 65;
    fprintf(file, "%s: %s -> ", variableName, input);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        input[i] = (char)(input[i] ^ a);//I am causing a segmentation fault
        fprintf(file, "0x%x, ", input[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char *a = "MyString";
    char *in = malloc(sizeof(a));
    strcpy(in, a);
    FILE *file = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    obfuscate(file, in, "a");
    fclose(file);
    free(in);
}
```

Comment: @Blastfurnace i added explanation in comment, anyway am adding here again

Comment: Thank you. Comments are ephemeral and answers should stand on their own.